# What is the purpose of `denyInsert` in meteor-collection2?

Tags: meteor, database-schema, meteor-collection2

In the section of the docs for the denyInsert and denyUpdate options in [`aldeed:meteor-collection2`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#denyinsert-and-denyupdate), you have an option to set a field to `denyInsert`, which means any inserts containing that property/field will throw an error.

What's the use case for this over simply not specifying it in the schema, and use the `filter` option to remove properties that are not in the schema?

Comment: My guess would be that you don't want a value for the field initially, like for an "updatedOn" (Date) field. So later on, you would want a value during an update.

Comment: I read that example in the docs too, but I can't imagine why someone would want this. I would update the `updatedOn` field every time an insert and update is made, even if it's the first. Would you? I don't see any practical implications here

Comment: Yeah, maybe they were trying to cover edge cases. Who knows?